# Time of sound-signal

Tags: stft, speech-processing, time-frequency

Let's say I have a sound file, I then compute the Spectrogram and segment each part of it. Assume that it is a recording of someone saying the word "Hello" and therefore, each piece is given like so:

```
0 -> H
1 -> E
2 -> L
3 -> L 
4 -> O
```

Now I want to calculate the duration of each of the parts/phonemes. Is there a way to do this? I was thinking, because I have the data, is it possible to just count the total number of elements and therefore calculate the time it takes?

Could anyone suggest any reading material that could potentially help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have the data"?

Comment: @user7358 Hey, basically, I have the data that represents the extracted data. So in this case, I have the specific calls (these are 128 blocks of values) since I use `N = 256` `noverlap = 128` when computing the STFT. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you know the sampling rate and overlap used in the STFT computation, you basically know the time in seconds from one "time pixel" to the next. So, count the number of "time pixels" for each of the 4 letters H,E,L,L,O and convert to seconds.

For example: $f_s = 44.1kHz$, N=256 and 50% overlap, each time pixel is 128/44.1 ms. If your letter "H" lasts P pixels, then the time duration is $128/44.1 \times P$ milliseconds.

Comment: @Atul Ingle Thanks :) But, what would $P$ be in this respect?

Comment: You can count the number of "time pixels" for an individual letter/phoneme in the spectrogram. That's P.

Comment: @AtulIngle Thanks for the reply. Sorry to ask you again. Each of the blocks inside of the segments are of size `128` that means that it would be: `128 / 44.1 * 128` - That does not make much sense though.. Or is P the number of pixels that warrant for time?

Comment: P is not 128. How many samples wide is one phoneme in the spectrogram image? That's P.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13238/discussion-between-user1326876-and-atul-ingle)